# How can i draw a lineString between two point in OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have to draw a lineString between between my two points for example: between [-110000, 4600000] and [0, 0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a feature that has a linestring geometry defined, then add it your vector source.

Example:

```
vectorSource.addFeature(
    new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.LineString([
            [-110000, 4600000],
            [0, 0]
        ])
    })
)
```

This [custom interation example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/custom-interactions.html) from openlayers.org demonstrates this.

Comment: Perfect what I was looking!!